# Ionic slide box not working

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using this on my ionic project

> https://github.com/saravmajestic/ionic/tree/master/tabbedSlideBox

and I have the following pages

```
            <tab-slide-box class="tabbed-slidebox">

        <div class="tsb-icons" >
            <div class="tsb-ic-wrp" >
                <ion-scroll direction="x" class="tsb-hscroll">
                    <a href="javascript:;">NEW (1) </a>
                    <a href="javascript:;">MATCHED (2)</a>
                    <a href="javascript:;" >SHORTLISTED (3)</a>
                    <a href="javascript:;">KIV (4)</a>
                    <a href="javascript:;">REJECTED (5) </a>
                    <a href="javascript:;">FOREIGNER (6)</a>
                    <a href="javascript:;">UNQUALIFIED (7)</a>
                    <a href="javascript:;">TOTAL (8)</a>
                </ion-scroll>
            </div>
        </div>


        <ion-slide-box show-pager="false" on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)" >

            <ion-slide>

            new content
            </ion-slide>


                <ion-slide>
                    <h1>Matched content</h1>
                </ion-slide>
                <ion-slide>
                    <h1>Shortlisted content</h1>
                </ion-slide>
                <ion-slide>
                    <h1>KIV content</h1>
                </ion-slide>
                <ion-slide>
                    <h1>Rejected content</h1>
                </ion-slide>
                <ion-slide>
                    <h1>Foreigner content</h1>
                </ion-slide>
                <ion-slide>
                    <h1>Unqualified content</h1>
                </ion-slide>
                <ion-slide>
                    <h1>Total content</h1>
                </ion-slide>

        </ion-slide-box>
    </tab-slide-box>
```

but it always lands on the 4th tab. How do i set it to land on the first tab (new)

Comment: edit the question if you want any other functionality.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

In the slide tab you are using, there is a file `tabSlideBox.js` it has this code

```
var initialIndex = attrs.tab;
//Initializing the middle tab
if(typeof attrs.tab === 'undefined' || (totalTabs <= initialIndex) || initialIndex < 0){
initialIndex = Math.floor(icons.length/2);
}
```

change that to

```
var initialIndex = 0
```

**Normal ionic tabs**

Use this

```
 $ionicTabsDelegate .select(`your tab index`, false);
```

check this [example](http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/Lszbq)

Comment: the example is not what I am doing, I am adding a sliding tab in the page, and I tried that code it doesn't work :/

Comment: oh if it doesn't work, it will give some error..paste console log here

Comment: Thank you, is there any way that I can change the page from my controller ?

Comment: you can change that it directly in file, it will not give any problem.

Comment: For my case, I need to be able to change different slides. So is there a way, in which i can set up a scope and feed it a number and it change slides ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137744/discussion-between-varun-aaruru-and-noor).